# Hadoop config issues on AWS - Cannot assign requested address / Failed on connection exception -

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to setup a small Hadoop cluster on AWS. I've been able to get to the point where I start the cluster but it keeps failing on the secondary namenode, which is supposed to be running on the primary namenode. I can access the datanodes via the web browser on hostname:50075 but The namenode cannot be accessed via hostname:50070.

Here are the two errors I spotted in the .log and .out file.

.log

[image]

and here is the .out

[image]

The guide I'm following has us setup our secondary on our primary namenode.

I've tried a few things including changing the formatting in the /etc/host file. I think it has to do with one of these config files.

/etc/hosts

[image]

I've put the public ip followed by the private ip provided by AWS.

/hadoop/etc/hadoop/masters

[image]

This is the masters file which tells the cluster where the secondary name node is.

Here is how it looks when I run the start-dfs.sh script. I'm not sure if the namenode should have 0.0.0.0 like it shows.

[image]

Any help is appreciated as I don't know what else to check.

Comment: Why not consider the AWS EMR service? It will bring up the instances and cluster for you, without much manual configurations.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to stand up a cluster from scratch

Comment: Though I am not too familiar with Hadoop, but from bind exception it seems there might be something already running on that port. What does netstat say about this port?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ran `sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 9000` and got no output. Does this mean that port is not open on my server? How can I fix that?

Comment: That would mean nothing is listening on that port. Did you try specifying any other port instead of 9000, maybe 9001/2 does that also give this same error?

Comment: Yes, I tried changing to 9001 earlier today. Same result. So something with the Hadoop config is incorrect? The Hadoop config needs to tell the server to listen right?

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012822/cannot-assign-requested-address