# Run mvnw failed by java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: java, maven, jhipster, bind

Installing jhipster and create sample `blog` with `jhipster`

cat /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#192.168.1.9    localhost
```

check pom.xml and define used port is `8090`
[image]

check running port:
[image]
Above shows that port `8090` is not used, and `./mvnw` should be able to run in given port

After run `./mvnw` it keeps saying `java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address`.

I use ubuntu 18.04 install both java 8 and 11 from [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04) and run maven in both

nb: already apply solution from similar question such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012822/cannot-assign-requested-address), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965155/cannot-assign-requested-address-using-serversocket-socketbind), with some points out that an error with `/etc/hosts`. After change my `/etc/hosts` like above, it still leaves me with same error

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Could you please add full error with stack trace if any. Maybe it's not about the servlet port, depending on which options you selected, it could be another port (see https://www.jhipster.tech/common-ports/) or maybe not related to ports at all.

Comment: seen your link, and none of them was running on my ubuntu, so it should be no problem. Full log [here](https://pastebin.com/ZtSUEpEw). Thanks btw

Comment: OK, so it's not about ports, only about IP address. You could set a breakpoint in Undertow.start() under debugger to inspect what it really binds to.